# How can I start a non-runnable Java file (.jar) with a console (cmd) open to display outputs without using something like mvn exec:java

Tags: java, maven, batch-file, cmd

I know there's threads similar to this one have been posted before but after reading through many of them, I still haven't found my answer.
What I have is a .jar file and I want to be able to run it with a command line output. I've tried java -jar .jar but it just closes the window instantly and I don't want to use mvn exec:java as I need to just have the jar file without pom.xml and also not need to have maven installed on the running machine.
Any ideas of how to do this?

Comment: Not sure if this will address your need, but you might look into using Stork, it can build your app into an executable / daemon for Windows/Mac/Linux.  https://github.com/fizzed/stork

Comment: Does `javaw -jar file.jar` help?

Comment: Are you sure, that Is your JAR contains java class with main() method?

Comment: What do you mean by "closes the window instantly"?  Is it erroring out?  Is it closing the cmd window you're running the command in?

Comment: Are you trying to do this from a windows batch (cmd) script?  And you're saying when you click to run, it briefly shows the console window, then that window closes while the program keeps running?

Comment: you could create executable jar files.

Comment: @RomanPuchkovskiy Tried that and doesn't work sadly.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166012/discussion-on-question-by-615283-how-can-i-start-a-non-runnable-java-file-jar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run the program indicating the jar in the classpath.

Assuming you are in the folder with the jar:

```
java -cp myjar.jar mypackage.MainClass
```

The reason the window closes immediately is because with the `-jar` option, `java` will look for a manifest file to know which is the main class. As the jar is not executable, `java` prints a message saying it didn't find a manifest file and exits, which closes the window.